# Rails: Helper method behaving differently between console and application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a helper method that can download a CSV file from S3 storage, read the first few rows of the file and then save those first few rows to a new local file.

All is working well when I include the helper in the rails console and call the methods on the object, but when calling it in exactly the same way through the controller, the local file contains all of the rows from the S3 file, rather than just the first few.

My code, in the helper file (I've replaced AWS credentials with comments for the purpose of posting the question):

```
def download_file(data_source)
  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(#API keys etc.)

  File.open(data_source.file.data['id'], 'wb') do |file|
    reap = s3.get_object({ bucket:#Bucket Name, key: 'store/' + data_source.file.data['id'] }, target: file)
  end
end

def reduce_csv(filename)
  data = CSV.open(filename, 'r') { |csv| csv.first(3) }
  csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    data.each do |d|
      csv << d
    end
  end
  File.open('test.csv', 'wb') do |file|
    file << csv_string
  end
end

def make_small_data_source(data_source)
  download_file(data_source)
  reduce_csv(data_source.file.data['id'])
end
```

And in the controller:

```
if @data_source.save
  make_small_data_source(@data_source)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: I tested your code and it's working perfectly. My `*.csv` file has just three lines of data. I tested running the helper directly and calling from controller. Both cases worked fine. Maybe you want to share your `*.csv`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was something to do with my `*.csv` file but adding `row_sep: :auto` to the CSV.open call fixed it. Thanks for getting me thinking about the CSV itself!